# How extract extract specific text from pdf file - python

Tags: python, web-crawler, pypdf

I am trying to extract this text:

```
 DLA LAND AND MARITIME
ACTIVE DEVICES DIVISION
PO BOX 3990
COLUMBUS OH 43218-3990
USA
 Name: Desmond Forshey Buyer Code:PMCMTA9 Tel: 614-692-6154 Fax:   614-692-6930
 Email: Desmond.Forshey@dla.mil
```

from this [pdf file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uKGG-V4NFsLAerf6jNRCs9kRwWRDxSx_). I was able to extract some text between two references using the code below:

```
import PyPDF2


pdfFileObj = open('SPE7M518T446E.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

print(pdfReader.numPages)

pageObj1 = pdfReader.getPage(0)
pagecontent = pageObj1.extractText()


def between(value, a, b):
    # Find and validate before-part.
    pos_a = value.find(a)
    if pos_a == -1: return ""
    # Find and validate after part.
    pos_b = value.rfind(b)
    if pos_b == -1: return ""
    # Return middle part.
    adjusted_pos_a = pos_a + len(a)
    if adjusted_pos_a >= pos_b: return ""
    return value[adjusted_pos_a:pos_b]

desired = between(pagecontent,"5. ","8. ")
print(desired)
```

The code above outputs this:

```
20
REQUEST FOR QUOTATIONSTHIS RFQ           IS             IS NOT A SMALL BUSINESS SET-ASIDE 4. CERT.FOR NAT. DEF.      UNDER BDSA REG. 2      AND/OR DMS REG. 15. ISSUED BY7. DELIVERY   9. DESTINATION10. PLEASE FURNISH QUOTATIONS TO THE       ISSUING OFFICE IN BLOCK 5 ON OR  BEFORE CLOSE OF BUSINESS (Date)IMPORTANT: This is a request for information,  and quotations furnished are  not offers. If you are unable  to quote, please so indicate on this form and return it to the  address in Block 5.   This  request  does not commit the Government to pay any costs incurred  in  the preparation of the submission of this  quotation or to contract for supplies  or services. Supplies are of domestic origin unless otherwise indicated by quoter. Any representations and/or certifications attached to this Request for Quotations must be completed by  the quoter.11. SCHEDULE  (See Continuation Sheets)     12. DISCOUNT FOR PROMPT PAYMENTd. CALENDAR DAYSNUMBERPERCENTAGE  NOTE:   Additional   provisions   and   representations                    are             are not attached.13. NAME AND ADDRESS OF QUOTERa. NAME OF QUOTER16. SIGNERAUTHORIZED FOR LOCAL REPRODUCTION Previous edition not useableSTANDARD FORM 18       (REV. 6-95)     Prescribed by GSA-FAR (48 CFR) 53.215-1(a)    SPE7M5-18-T-446E1. REQUEST NO.2018 APR 302. DATE ISSUED00739229623. REQUISITION/PURCHASE REQUEST NO.DO-C9RATINGDLA LAND AND MARITIME 
ACTIVE DEVICES DIVISION 
PO BOX 3990 
COLUMBUS OH  43218-3990 
USA 
Name: Desmond Forshey Buyer Code:PMCMTA9 Tel: 614-692-6154 Fax: 614-692-6930 
Email: Desmond.Forshey@dla.mil175 DAYS ADO 6. DELIVER BY  (Date)8. TO: c. CITYd. STATE b. STREET ADDRESS a. NAME OF CONSIGNEEe. ZIP CODE a. 10 CALENDAR DAYS (%)b. 20 CALENDAR DAYS (%) c. 30 CALENDAR DAYS (%)15. Date of Quotationa. NAME (Type or Print)  
AREA CODEc. TITLE (Type or Print)d. CITY  c. COUNTY    b. STREET ADDRESSe. STATE f. ZIP CODESee  Schedule2018 MAY 10NUMBERFOB DESTINATIONOTHER  (See Schedule)CAGE          b. TELEPHONE PAGE     OF      PAGES1 
POC INFORMATION: 

WHEN TECHNICAL DATA IS PROVIDED IT MUST BE OBTAINED AT:https://pcf1x.bsm.dla.mil/cfolders. DISCREPANCIES FOUND IN TECHNICAL DATA SHOULD SUBMIT 
REQUEST TO THE DLA CUSTOMER SERVICE WEBSITE:https://www.pdmd.dla.mil/cs/ 

ALL OTHER QUESTIONS (SOLICITATION REQUIREMENTS, ITEM DESCRIPTION, AWARD CHOICE, ETC.), PLEASE CONTACT THE BUYER SHOWN ABOVE. 

QUESTIONS REGARDING OPERATION OF THE DLA-BSM INTERNET BID BOARD SYSTEM SHOULD BE E-MAILED TO: DibbsBSM@dla.mil 

FOR IMMEDIATE ASSISTANCE, PLEASE REFER TO THE FREQUENTLY ASKED QUESTIONS (FAQS) ON BSM DIBBS AT: 
https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/Refs/help/DIBBSHelp.htm  OR PHONE 1-855-DLA-0001 (1-855-352-0001). 


MASTER SOLICITATION 

THIS SOLICITATION INCORPORATES THE TERMS AND CONDITIONS SET FORTH IN THE DLA MASTER SOLICITATION FOR AUTOMATED SIMPLIFIED 
ACQUISITIONS REVISION 46 (FEBRURARY 7, 2018) WHICH CAN BE FOUND ON THE WEB AT: 
http://www.dla.mil/Portals/104/Documents/J7Acquisition/Master%20Solicitation%20Rev-46%20February-7-2018.pdf?ver=2018-02-08-063754-70 

This solicitation incorporates technical/quality requirements (‚R™ or ‚I™ number in section B). The full text is in the DLA Technical and Quality Master List of Requirements at: 
http://www.dla.mil/HQ/Acquisition/Offers/eprocurement.aspx The revisionof the TQ Master in effect on the award date controls.14. SIGNATURE OF PERSON AUTHORIZED TO SIGN QUOTATION 1                20
###################
ISSUED BY7. DELIVERY   9. DESTINATION10. PLEASE FURNISH QUOTATIONS TO THE       ISSUING OFFICE IN BLOCK 5 ON OR  BEFORE CLOSE OF BUSINESS (Date)IMPORTANT: This is a request for information,  and quotations furnished are  not offers. If you are unable  to quote, please so indicate on this form and return it to the  address in Block 5.   This  request  does not commit the Government to pay any costs incurred  in  the preparation of the submission of this  quotation or to contract for supplies  or services. Supplies are of domestic origin unless otherwise indicated by quoter. Any representations and/or certifications attached to this Request for Quotations must be completed by  the quoter.11. SCHEDULE  (See Continuation Sheets)     12. DISCOUNT FOR PROMPT PAYMENTd. CALENDAR DAYSNUMBERPERCENTAGE  NOTE:   Additional   provisions   and   representations                    are             are not attached.13. NAME AND ADDRESS OF QUOTERa. NAME OF QUOTER16. SIGNERAUTHORIZED FOR LOCAL REPRODUCTION Previous edition not useableSTANDARD FORM 18       (REV. 6-95)     Prescribed by GSA-FAR (48 CFR) 53.215-1(a)    SPE7M5-18-T-446E1. REQUEST NO.2018 APR 302. DATE ISSUED00739229623. REQUISITION/PURCHASE REQUEST NO.DO-C9RATINGDLA LAND AND MARITIME 
ACTIVE DEVICES DIVISION 
PO BOX 3990 
COLUMBUS OH  43218-3990 
USA 
Name: Desmond Forshey Buyer Code:PMCMTA9 Tel: 614-692-6154 Fax: 614-692-6930 
Email: Desmond.Forshey@dla.mil175 DAYS ADO 6. DELIVER BY  (Date)
```

How can I extract the text below from the PDF file ?

```
DLA LAND AND MARITIME
ACTIVE DEVICES DIVISION
PO BOX 3990
COLUMBUS OH 43218-3990
USA
Name: Desmond Forshey Buyer Code:PMCMTA9 Tel: 614-692-6154 Fax:   614-692-6930
Email: Desmond.Forshey@dla.mil
```

Comment: Trivial edit suggestion (because I can't edit this post myself): "How extract extract" should be "how to extract." I noticed because another question linked to this, which is a good sign that this is a useful question someone else might link to, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That PDF reader doesn't give much scope for interacting with the structure of the returned data. It is though possible to add a new function to it that returns each element as another item in a list. You would then at least be able to extract the data between two items. The approach is still not foolproof as you still need to decide on possible termination cases:

```
import PyPDF2
import itertools


def extractTextList(self):
    text_list = []
    content = self["/Contents"].getObject()
    if not isinstance(content, ContentStream):
        content = ContentStream(content, self.pdf)

    for operands, operator in content.operations:
        if operator == b_("Tj"):
            _text = operands[0]
            if isinstance(_text, TextStringObject) and len(_text.strip()):
                text_list.append(_text.strip())
        elif operator == b_("T*"):
            pass
        elif operator == b_("'"):
            pass
            _text = operands[0]
            if isinstance(_text, TextStringObject) and len(operands[0]):
                text_list.append(operands[0])
        elif operator == b_('"'):
            _text = operands[2]
            if isinstance(_text, TextStringObject) and len(_text):
                text_list.append(_text)
        elif operator == b_("TJ"):
            for i in operands[0]:
                if isinstance(i, TextStringObject) and len(i):
                    text_list.append(i)
    return text_list


from PyPDF2.pdf import PageObject, u_, ContentStream, b_, TextStringObject
PageObject.extractTextList = extractTextList


def between(text_elements, drop_while, take_while):    
    return list(itertools.takewhile(take_while, itertools.dropwhile(drop_while, text_elements)))[1:]    


pdfFileObj = open('SPE7M518T446E.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

page0 = pdfReader.getPage(0)
text_elements = page0.extractTextList()

lines = between(text_elements, lambda x: x != 'RATING', lambda x: 'DAYS' not in x)
print('\n'.join(lines))
```

This would give you the lines you want, which are then combined into a single output as follows:

```
DLA LAND AND MARITIME
ACTIVE DEVICES DIVISION
PO BOX 3990
COLUMBUS OH  43218-3990
USA
Name: Desmond Forshey Buyer Code:PMCMTA9 Tel: 614-692-6154 Fax: 614-692-6930
Email: Desmond.Forshey@dla.mil
```

As the new function `extractTextList()` returns a list of text elements found in the page, I use [`itertools.dropwhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) and [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to process the returned list.

The `between()` function works in two stages, first it reads the list of strings one at a time and discards them until it matches this first test (which is to find `RATING`). It then starts returning elements to the `takewhile()` function. This keeps taking elements until it spots the word `DAYS` in one of the elements. `list()` is used to create the filtered list. I then drop the first element (as it is the word `RATING`).

In effect this is an iterative way of doing a slice on the list.

Note: `lambda` is just another way of defining a function. In this case it takes a text element called `x` and returns `True` if it is a certain value, or for the takewhile, if the word `DAYS` is somewhere inside it. The two itertool functions call these lambda functions for each element in the list.

Comment: Thank you, could you please explain the code as much as you could because I have other data to retrieve from the pdf and I was hoping I could use the same logic from this answer to extract from other places in the pdf

Comment: I've improved the explanation and have created a `between()` function which you might be able to make more use of for other cases. I suggest you print `text_elements`, it would then be clearer how it is working.

Comment: Thank you so much. it's a life saver